# Identifying white space in a twig variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a situation where I need to identify if there is a blank space in a variable in a twig template, and to treat it slightly differently.

Given names in this application are stored with middle initials in the given name field; they are not stored separately.

What I'm trying to achieve is this: Typically most given names are one word, e.g. "John" or "Susan" or something similar.   In some of these cases we have cases where the middle initial is stored within this variable (e.g.  John J)

Following standard citation standards, we need to be able to list items like this:

```
{{ surname }}, {{ given_name }}, ed.
```

This way it would appear like "Smith, John, ed."   This is normally fine, however in some situations, where there is a middle initial, it appears as "Smith, John J, ed."  - this is incorrect.   I can't add a period after the given name, as "Smith, John., ed" would be an incorrect citation standard.

What I'm trying to do is to identify if a `given_name` contains a space, followed by a single letter, and then format it differently.

Something like this:

```
{% if given_name [has a blank space preceding a single letter] %}
{{ given_name }}., ed.
{% else %}
{{ given_name }}, ed.
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to do this with regex within twig, or is there another method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom twig extension to do all that for you?

Comment: `{{ given_name|split(' ')[0] }}` will remove everything after first space so `John J Hello` becomes `John`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry I gave you a simple answer too quickly, i thought you would have figured it out from my original solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can translate your requirement:

> has a blank space preceding a single letter

In this little algorithm:

```
{% set given_name = 'John J' %}

{% set given_name_elems = given_name|split(' ') %}

{% set size = given_name_elems|length %}


{% if size >0 and given_name_elems[size-1]|length == 1%}
   { given_name }}., ed.
{%else%}
   {{ given_name }}, ed.
{%endif%}
```

I suggest you to incapsulate this logic in a function or in a macro.

You could made some try in [this working example](https://twigfiddle.com/hvhfrc)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick;  just a bit of tweaking needed to get it working with my real case.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but is not necessarily going to handle edge cases well.  Assuming that you need to do the whole thing in twig, you could do something like this:

```
{% set nameArray = given_name | split(' ') %}
{% set first_name = nameArray[0] %}
{% set middle_initial = nameArray[1] is defined ? " "~nameArray[1]~"." : ""%}
```

At this point `middle_initial is now set to either an empty string or the middle initial with the period so you can output the full name like:

```
{{ surname }}, {{first_name ~ middle_initial}}, ed
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with the [`matches` comparison operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#comparisons) and add the dot if `given_name` matches the pattern.

```
{{ given_name }}{% if given_name matches '/^.+ .$/' %}.{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't give you a good answer initially. I've updated my code and my twigfiddle. It's a bit simpler than @Matteo 's:

```
{% set given_name = 'John J' %}
{% set nameArray = given_name|split(' ') %}

{% if nameArray[1] is defined %}
    {{ nameArray[0] }} {{ nameArray[1] }}., ed.
{% else %}
    {{ nameArray[0] }}, ed.
{% endif %}
```

Where `{{ nameArray[0] }}` specifies the first element of the array. If nameArray[1](https://twigfiddle.com/8uuno1) contains anything, then it is defined.

[Here is a working twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/8uuno1) to show you it works.